# How to send json data from android app and receive it in rest web service running in jersey?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, jersey

I have made my rest web service code to start sever like this :

```
static final String BASE_URI = "http://10.236.51.14:9000/abcd/";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Press Enter to stop the server. ");
        System.in.read();
        server.stop(0);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And in the rest web service I have made a basic code to receive 2 arguments and show their sum like this :

```
@GET
@Path("/add/{a}/{b}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String add(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<result>" +  (a + b)                 +     "</result>";
}
```

I want to send Json data (image) from my android app to this webservice but I don't know how to receive it in webservice and display it.
Here is the code from my android app. In this I have converted a bitmap to string using Base64. How should I send it to my webservice?

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String strBitMap = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Any help will be appreciated :)
I have searched a lot but cant find appropriate code for my webservice to receive and display the json data. I am also struggling in sending this base64 string to the webservice in form of json.
Please help me out.
Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a question: Does your example WebService work? I mean the one with the two arguments. If you call `http://10.236.51.14:9000/abcd/add/1/2` in your browser does it display 3 correctly? If not you should have an ApplicationConfig containing your REST-interfaces. Those should be added as resource classes for example like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.addAll(addServiceClasses());
        resources.addAll(addFilterClasses());
        return resources;
    }

    private Set<Class<?>> addServiceClasses() {

    // add all your REST-classes here
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(YourCalculatorRestServiceClass.class);
        resources.add(YourImageConsumingRestServiceClass.class);

        return resources;
    }

    private Set<Class<?>> addFilterClasses() {

    // add all your filter classes here (if you have any)
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();

        resources.add(YourAuthenticationFilterClass.class);
        resources.add(OtherFilterClass.class);

        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        // in Jersey WADL generation is enabled by default, but we don't 
        // want to expose too much information about our apis.
        // therefore we want to disable wadl (http://localhost:8080/service/application.wadl should return http 404)
        // see https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e9020 for details
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl", true);

        // we could also use something like this instead of adding each of our resources
        // explicitly in getClasses():
        // properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.nabisoft.tutorials.mavenstruts.service");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

That should make the deal and you should be able to call `http://10.236.51.14:9000/abcd/api/add/1/2`. ApplicationConfig is annotated with `@Path("api")`. That means all classes registered in this config have the root path `http://your.server.address/api/`.

Now to your problem. I assume your server is working and you can reach your Webservice `/add/1/2` displaying the result 3 in your browser.

Now you need another service listening for a `POST`. I'd take your already prepared `String` as the posted body.

```
@Path("image")
public class ImageReceiverRestService {

    @POST
    public Response checkAssignable(String base64ImageString) {
        // code here working with the base64ImageString

        // response code according to whatever happened during your algorithm
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

For appropriate HTTP response codes see this Wikipedia article for a quick overview [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

So now you'd need a corresponding client on your android app. For example:

```
public class ImageSendingRestClient {

    private final static String SERVER_BASE_URI = "http://10.236.51.14:9000/abcd/api/";
    private final static String API_ADDRESS = "image/";

    public ImageSendingRestClient() {
    }

    @Override
    public void sendImageStringForProcessing(String base64ImageString) throws Exception {
        Entity<String> entity = Entity.json(base64ImageString);

        Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                .target(SERVER_BASE_URI)
                .path(API_ADDRESS)
                .request()
                .post(entity);

        try {
            if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
                return;
            }
            if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode()) {
                throw new Exception;
            }
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }
}
```

All dependencies needed are JAX-RS implementations like [JAX-RS reference implementation Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/). Maybe you should also check the Jersey Guide with many examples providing most of the information you need [Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer Joe. Yes the server works fine for the addition command. When I put the image sending code in android studio, it is unable to identify Response , ClientBuilder etc. Do I need to import any library for them ?

Comment: yes of course. you need the `jersey-client` dependency for the client side and jersey-container dependency for server side. [Modules and Dependencies for Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html) may help here to find what you need. Or you can use  some other JAX-RS implementation. We use `<dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>`. Provided because we run jersey on a Glassfish 4.0 which ships with jersey